# Sending binary SMS over SMPP to change the APN

Tags: binary, sms, gsm, telecommunication, oma

I am using SMPP 3.4 to send a binary SMS over SMPP, where the SMSC acts as an SMPP server.
How to send a binary SMS based on OMA CP to change the APN settings?